# jQuery event handler organisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-manipulation

I am looking for a recommendation on the best way to organised my code. I have a lot of jQuery   event handle which are used for:

- dropdown menus, tabs etc
- form validation
- $.ajax get requests for dynamic form `<options>`'s
- $.ajax post requests for form submitting.

An MVC framework like backbonejs seems like overkill but my current code isn't maintainable and will continue to get worse unless i give it some kind of structure.

```
$('#detailsform').find('.field').on('click','.save',function(){
    var input = $(this).siblings().find('input');
    input.attr('type','hidden');
    $(this).siblings().find('p').text(input.val());
    $(this).text('Change').addClass('change').removeClass('save');
    url = null; //query str

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
});
//next event listener 
//next event listener 
//next event listener 
//next event listener
```

that is one of many event listeners. Any suggestions on how to organise this?

Comment: You can look into proper indentation of code. You need to think through what is common between all these event handlers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the following structure. Simply add more objects in the **eventHandlers** array for each element you need. This could even be done programatically.

```
(function() {
    var Site = {
        init: function() {
            this.bindEventHandlers();
        },
        bindEventHandlers: function() {
            for (var i=0; i<this.eventHandlers.length; i++) {
                this.bindEvent(this.eventHandlers[i]);
            }
        },
        bindEvent: function(e) {
            e.$el.on(e.event, e.handler);
            console.log('Bound ' + e.event + ' handler for', e.$el);
        },
        eventHandlers: [
            {
                $el: $('#element1'),
                event: "click",
                handler: function() { console.log('Clicked',$(this)) }
            },
            {
                $el: $('#element2'),
                event: "click",
                handler: function() { console.log('Clicked',$(this)) }
            }
        ]
    };

    Site.init();
})();
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/chrispickford/LQr2B/

Comment: Great, this looks very promising. Thank you. and an extra thanks for the jsfiddle. My post requests require a certain amount of validation. I've been looking at backbonejs and the model seems to handle things like this, should I have a separate 'model' which is called from within the handler method to perform the ajax requests and validation?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with BackboneJS so I couldn't comment on what it can or cannot do. If I were sticking with the above paradigm I would extend the Site object to include data validation methods and apply them at runtime using the eventHandlers. What you should be aiming for is to be creating [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).